# Prolog: what is difference between, for example, X is 3 and 3 is X?

Tags: prolog

```
three(X) :- 3 is X.

three2(X) :- X is 3.
```

Requests `three(3)`, `three(5)` and `three2(3)`, `three2(5)` respectively have the same answers.

But `three2(X)` has answer 3, while `three(X)` has answer `"Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"`.

If there's enough data to solve that `three(3)` is `true` and `three(5)` is `false`, why there's not enough data to find that `X` is equals `3` when we request for the value of `X`?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `is/2` is the numeric expression evaluator of Prolog. Everything on the *Right Hand Side* of `is/2` must be fully instantiated so that the expression can then be evaluated to a number (possibility missed: evaluate to something else than numbers). The result is then *unified* with the *Left Hand Side* of `is/2`. This succeeds if the LHS is an unbound variable or the same as the result obtained.

In your case, you can make the predicate `three/1` symmetric by just unifying, as there is really nothing to evaluate:

```
three_sym(X) :- 3 = X.
```

Succeeds with `3` and outputs the answer `X = 3` for an unbound `X`.